# How to launch an external application in a "customized" activity from my application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I know that the following  there lines of code will enable me to go form app to the Facebook.

```
Intent FacebookApp= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Facebook package name");
                startActivity(FacebookApp);
```

However, If I want to go from my app to the Facebook app where I show the facebook app in a new activity that has a button at the bottom. This bottom, if clicked, will show a toast message.  this what i meant by the "customized activity" (i.e shows both the Facebook app and a button).

How can I do that?

Comment: you can open fb in webview just pass the URL

Comment: but , what about the button ?

Comment: you can customize webviews..

Comment: what i mean , i do not want to open Facebook form using the URL...I want to open it by from my app to the Facebook on my phone